# Quantlib : How fixingValueDate_/fixingEndDate_ different from coupon startDate/endDate

Tags: quantlib

Which is the right start date and end date to be used to get interest rate from forward curve? What is the need for fixingValueDate_ and fixingEndDate_?

In below method, fixingValueDate_ and fixingEndDate_ are used

```
IborCoupon::indexFixing()
{
...

return iborIndex_->forecastFixing(fixingValueDate_,
                                          fixingEndDate_,
                                          spanningTime_);
}
```

If you check in `IborCoupon::IborCoupon()`, `fixingValueDate_` and `fixingEndDate_` are nothing but `accrualStartDate_` and `accrualEndDate_` because of following:

(In case of in-arrears is false)

```
(1) fixingDate_ = accrualStartDate_  - spotDays
(2) fixingValueDate_ = fixingDate_ + spotdays = accrualStartDate_  
(3) nextFixingDate = accrualEndDate_  - spotDays
(4) fixingEndDate_ = nextFixingDate + spotDays = accrualEndDate_
```

What is point of calculating `fixingValueDate_` and `fixingEndDate_` ...

Can we not use `accrualStartDate_` and `accrualEndDate_` ...

Also I think Quantlib does not support multiple resets within one coupon period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start and end dates of the coupon are not always the same as the start and end date of the underlying LIBOR fixing.

The more obvious case is when the coupon is paid in arrears.  In that case, the rate is fixed at the end of the coupon.

The less obvious case is when the dates differ due to adjustments.  For instance, consider a 1-year swap starting January 7th, 2013 and ending January 7th, 2014 with semiannual floating coupons.  July 7th, 2013 is a Sunday, so the coupon dates will adjust.  The first coupon goes from January 7th to June 8th, and the second coupon goes from June 8th to January 7th.

For the first coupon, the dates are equal, as you say.  For the second, they're not.  The start date is June 8th, and equals the value date of the fixing.  The end date of the coupon, however, is January 7th, whereas the maturity date of the fixing is 6 months after its value date, that is, January 8th.  A small difference, but a difference nonetheless.

Comment: For getting the forward rate, below dates need to be used:

forwardStartDate : (coupon start date - spotdays)
forwardEndDate : forwardStartDate + Tenor (e.g. 6M)


Coupon end date should not be used to get the forwardEndDate

I am afraid QuantLIb is not doing the above...In quantlib, forwardEndDate is based on Coupon End date, which I think is wrong.

Kindly correct me if you think otherwise.

Comment: The coupon can be calculated at par (the default, with the end of the coupon being used) or over the actual index tenor. The behavior can be chosen via a compilation switch. See http://www.implementingquantlib.com/2017/07/notebook-par-coupons.html for some more details.